# how can I order this by rate using only mutate() and filter() function

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, rank, mutate

```
> murders <- mutate(murders, rate = total/population*100000, rank = rank(-rate))
> filter(murders, rank <= 5)
                 state abb        region population total      rate rank
1 District of Columbia  DC         South     601723    99 16.452753    1
2            Louisiana  LA         South    4533372   351  7.742581    2
3             Maryland  MD         South    5773552   293  5.074866    4
4             Missouri  MO North Central    5988927   321  5.359892    3
5       South Carolina  SC         South    4625364   207  4.475323    5
```

why "Maryland"(rank 4) is above "Missouri"(rank 3)

Comment: You need to sort it, read about arrange: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html

Comment: yes after applying the arrange() fn did solved the issue, but is it possible with only using mutate and filter.

Comment: "is it possible with only using mutate and filter?".  No.

Comment: @Limey, you could do something like `mutate(across(everything(), ~ .[order(-rate)]))` ?  (or use `slice()` instead of bracket-indexing)

Comment: @mit_ran, if you edit your question slightly ("how can I order this by rate using only `mutate()` and `filter()`?") it could be re-opened ...

Comment: @BenBolker  As I hit <return> on my comment, I thought, "I bet someone will take that as a challenge and come up with a way to do it...".  I suppose it's possible, but I think Occam's Razor applies: why would you when `... %>% mutate() %>% arrange()` will do the job reliably, simply and with clarity of intent?

Comment: (1) constraints of a homework assignment (2) code puzzle/golf ?

Comment: @BenBolker I like the challenge, but is it even possible without using any ordering, including order, sort, arrange, slice, topn, etc.

Comment: @zx8754, that's starting to seem like masochism. Hard to imagine how the problem could be solvable under those constraints ... ?  (Short of implementing your own sorting algorithm from scratch, of course, which would involve only comparisons and branching, not use of any built-in ordering functions ...)

Comment: (If you don't want the word "sort" to appear *in your code*, you could use: `myfun <- get(grep("^sor.$", ls("package:base"), value = TRUE))` ... :-)

Comment: It's not absolutely necessary, but it would be helpful to explain *why* you want to restrict yourself to using `mutate` and `filter` ...

Answer (score 0):

Below are a few ways to do it:

The first uses only dplyr and here `mutate` and `filter`:

The second uses `slice` which makes things easier.

The third way uses base r only.

To answer your question, why in your approach "Maryland" is above "Missouri": `rank()` just assigns values according to the rank, it doesn't sort the rows accordingly.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)


# dplyr: only mutate and filter (and only one pipe)
murders |>
  mutate(rate = total/population*100000,
         rank = rank(-rate)) |> 
  filter(rank <= 5) |> 
  mutate(pick(everything())[.data[["rank"]], ])
#>                  state abb        region population total      rate rank
#> 1 District of Columbia  DC         South     601723    99 16.452753    1
#> 2            Louisiana  LA         South    4533372   351  7.742581    2
#> 3             Missouri  MO North Central    5988927   321  5.359892    3
#> 4             Maryland  MD         South    5773552   293  5.074866    4
#> 5       South Carolina  SC         South    4625364   207  4.475323    5

# dplyr: slice
murders |>
  mutate(rate = total/population*100000,
         rank = rank(-rate)) |> 
  filter(rank <= 5) |> 
  slice(rank)
#>                  state abb        region population total      rate rank
#> 1 District of Columbia  DC         South     601723    99 16.452753    1
#> 2            Louisiana  LA         South    4533372   351  7.742581    2
#> 3             Missouri  MO North Central    5988927   321  5.359892    3
#> 4             Maryland  MD         South    5773552   293  5.074866    4
#> 5       South Carolina  SC         South    4625364   207  4.475323    5

# base R 
murders2 <- murders |> 
  transform(rate = total/population*100000) |> 
  transform(rank = rank(-rate)) |>   
  subset(rank <= 5)

murders2[murders2$rank, ]

#>                   state abb        region population total      rate rank
#> 9  District of Columbia  DC         South     601723    99 16.452753    1
#> 19            Louisiana  LA         South    4533372   351  7.742581    2
#> 26             Missouri  MO North Central    5988927   321  5.359892    3
#> 21             Maryland  MD         South    5773552   293  5.074866    4
#> 41       South Carolina  SC         South    4625364   207  4.475323    5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Which Theme you're using in RStudio

Comment: @mit_ran: the above is not a screen shot, its the [{reprex}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/index.html) package. Btw. I'm using the cobalt theme in RStudio and the Cobalt2 Theme in VS Code.